# How would I quick sort this type horse which is a 2-tuple consisting of a String (the horse’s name) and an Int (the horse’s height in centimetres)

Tags: haskell, quicksort

I am trying to quick sort it in ascending order by the height of each horse. An example of he list is [("Thunder",125),("Lightning",115),("Bolt",135)].

I have tried the following ;

```
type Horse = (String, Int)
sort_horse_list :: [Horse] -> [Horse]
sort_horse_list horses = quick_sort horses
    (\h1 h2 -> snd h1 <= snd h2)
```

the desired output would be [("Lightning",115),("Thunder",125),("Bolt",135)].

Comment: So, you already have implemented `quick_sort`? What's its siganture?

Comment: Tuples are comparable; you just want to sort *different* tuples, namely `(Int, String)` instead of `(String, Int)`. Try `map swap . quick_sort . map swap` (where `swap` can be imported from `Data.Tuple`, but is trivially defined as `swap (a, b) = (b, a)`.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of `quick_sort` function you are using, as already commented by [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784231/how-would-i-quick-sort-this-type-horse-which-is-a-2-tuple-consisting-of-a-string/74785554#comment131983068_74784231). It is hard to give you an exact answer without knowing the type of the quicksort algorithm you are using. I did however create an implementation using the `sortBy` and `comparing` functions. The `sortBy` function does not use quicksort (it uses mergesort) so this is not a valid solution if you have to use quicksort:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

type Horse = (String, Int)
sort_horse_list :: [Horse] -> [Horse]
sort_horse_list = sortBy (comparing $ snd)
```

It can be used like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = let xs = [("Thunder",125),("Lightning",115),("Bolt",135)] in do
    print (sort_horse_list xs)
```

Comment: These days, I usually recommend `sortOn` rather than `sortBy . comparing`. `sortOn` does the same thing but faster, and I don't think I've ever seen `sortBy` used without `comparing` immediately after.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I agree! I am fairly new to Haskell myself, and didn't know about this function.